# websockets with ssl

Tags: javascript, python, ssl

Есть http страница на html и js, прекрасно работает с websockets сервером python. Потребность в переходе страницы на https с использованием сертификатов от certbot. Сертификаты получил и страница работает по https, но теперь она не подключается по websocket к серверу. Итог

1. у меня есть страница на домене, она https и должна подключаться к серверу через 'wss//ip-сервера'
2. у меня есть сервер, на котором я подключил к websockets сертификаты ssl своего домена.
   Когда не заморачивался с ssl всё работало, но теперь сайт не подключается к серверу
   "Firefox не может установить соединение с сервером wss://"

Надеюсь советовать открыть порт не будут...